# How to make a candidate key unique with nullable column

Tags: sql

I need a candidate key by adding three columns to it, out of which one column is nullable, but i need to use it. I have tried adding a check constraint to the nullable column and if null replacing it with unique id but sicei am new to sql developer cannot perform this. Anybody who could suggest new way or show me the step to add a check to the constraint.

Comment: Show us your attempt. And add a question tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Add the DDL of the table.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Don't create a `PRIMARY KEY`, instead create a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED CONSTRAINT` (if your DBMS allows) as this will give you all the good parts of a primary key without the dumb restriction that columns can't be nullable.

Comment: Richard Hansell you mean i should make the constraint unique? Thanks or your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary key cannot be null.  Same for a composite primary key.

A unique constraint can have a nullable column.

If you want to use it as a PK then make it non null and a assign a default value that takes on the meaning of null.

Answer (score 0):

Per definition, a candidate key "should be able at any time to become the primary key of the table." That's why is a **candidate key**.

Therefore, it cannot include a nullable column.